# How do I use the metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect method and rectOfInterest property to scan a specific area? (QR Code)

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, avcapturesession

I am building a QR code scanner with Swift and everything works in that regard.  The issue I have is that I am trying to make only a small area of the entire visible `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` be able to scan QR codes.  I have found out that in order to specify what area of the screen will be able to read/capture QR codes I would have to use a property of `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` called `rectOfInterest`.  The trouble is when I assigned that to a CGRect, I couldn't scan anything.  After doing more research online I have found some suggesting that I would need to use a method called `metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect` to convert a CGRect into a correct format that the property `rectOfInterest` can actually use.  HOWEVER, the big issue I have run into now is that when I use this method `metadataoutputRectOfInterestForRect` I am getting an error that states `CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix`.  Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?  I believe I am using this method properly according to the Apple developer documentation and I believe I need to use this according to all the information I have found online to accomplish my goal.  I will include links to the documentation I have found so far as well as a code sample of the function I am using to scan QR codes

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
func startScan() {
        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video
        // as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
        var error:NSError?
        let input: AnyObject! = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: &error)

        if (error != nil) {
            // If any error occurs, simply log the description of it and don't continue any more.
            println("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        // Initialize the captureSession object.
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        // Set the input device on the capture session.
        captureSession?.addInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)

        // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
        let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

        // calculate a centered square rectangle with red border
        let size = 300
        let screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
        let xPos = (CGFloat(screenWidth) / CGFloat(2)) - (CGFloat(size) / CGFloat(2))
        let scanRect = CGRect(x: Int(xPos), y: 150, width: size, height: size)

        // create UIView that will server as a red square to indicate where to place QRCode for scanning
        scanAreaView = UIView()
        scanAreaView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        scanAreaView?.layer.borderWidth = 4
        scanAreaView?.frame = scanRect
        view.addSubview(scanAreaView!)

        // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
        captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]



        // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        captureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest = videoPreviewLayer!.metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect(scanRect)
        view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

        // Start video capture.
        captureSession?.startRunning()

        // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
        qrCodeFrameView = UIView()
        qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView!)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView!)

        // Add a button that will be used to close out of the scan view
        videoBtn.setTitle("Close", forState: .Normal)
        videoBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        videoBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        videoBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        videoBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 70, 45)
        videoBtn.addTarget(self, action: "pressClose:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(videoBtn)


        view.bringSubviewToFront(scanAreaView!)

    }
```

Please note that the line of interest causing the error is this:
`captureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest = videoPreviewLayer!.metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect(scanRect)`

Other things I have tried are passing in a CGRect directly as a parameter and that has caused the same error.  I have also passed in `scanAreaView!.bounds` as a parameter as that is really the exact size/area I am looking for and that also causes the same exact error.  I have seen this done in other's code examples online and they do not seem to have the errors I am having.  Here are some examples:

[AVCaptureSession barcode scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734929/avcapturesession-barcode-scan)

[Xcode AVCapturesession scan Barcode in specific frame (rectOfInterest is not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634036/xcode-avcapturesession-scan-barcode-in-specific-frame-rectofinterest-is-not-wor)

**Apple documentation**

[metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureOutput_Class/index.html)

[rectOfInterest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureMetadataOutput/)

Image of scanAreaView I am using as the designated area I am trying to make the only scannable area of the video preview layer:

[image]

Comment: What can be used if using AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate's func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)  instead ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I wasn't really able to clarify the issue with metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect, however, you can directly set the property as well. You need to the have the resolution in width and height of your video, which you can specify in advance. I quickly used the 640*480 setting. As stated in the documentation, these values have to be

> "extending from (0,0) in the top left to (1,1) in the bottom right, relative to the device’s natural orientation".

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureoutput/1616304-metadataoutputrectofinterestforr

Below is the code I tried

```
var x = scanRect.origin.x/480
var y = scanRect.origin.y/640
var width = scanRect.width/480
var height = scanRect.height/640
var scanRectTransformed = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
captureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest = scanRectTransformed
```

I just tested it on an iOS device and it seems to work.

**Edit**

At least I've solved the metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect problem. I believe you have to do this after the camera has been properly set up and is running, as the camera's resolution is not yet available.

First, add a notification observer method within viewDidLoad()

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("avCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification:"), name:AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Then add the following method

```
func avCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

    captureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest = videoPreviewLayer.metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect(scanRect)

}
```

Here you can then reset the rectOfInterest property. Then, in your code, you can display the AVMetadataObject within the didOutputMetadataObjects function

```
var rect = videoPreviewLayer.rectForMetadataOutputRectOfInterest(YourAVMetadataObject.bounds)

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
     self.qrCodeFrameView.frame = rect
})
```

I've tried, and the rectangle was always within the specified area.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I tried using the code you provided and unfortunately it didn't work for me.  I updated the 640*480 values to be 1024*768 as I am using an iPad and not a phone but the scan area was not within the designated scanRect I am using as target area.  I added an image of the UIView in my app to the question above to show better what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: See the updated post, I've solved the issue with metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect and it seems to work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Mine was not scanning whatsoever before. Fixed my issue :)

Comment: For me it's still unclear. I am using the exact same code, and the whole screen is not capturent, but neither the area i defined. It's like if the (0, 0) insu starting on the top left corner..

Comment: Your first option worked for me but the metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect isn't, i tried everything but i really don't know what i need to make it work.

Comment: @DKrautkramer For me its not working can you share some code which works for you. For me captureOutput method not getting called

Comment: Setting the converted rectOfInterest in a handler for AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChange works for me in iOS 11 beta 4

Comment: could this be used with vision text detect to have a rectangle only recognise text rather than the whole screen?

Comment: @DKrautkramer Have you resolved the issue  ? I am also trying to do the same but in starting I used AVCapturePhotoOutput instead of AVCaptureMetadataOutput, but eventually after seeing so many answers pointing to AVCaptureMetadataOutput, still not able to use it properly. Can you guide in right direct, code share?

Answer (score 27):

In iOS 9.3.2 I was able to make `metadataoutputRectOfInterestForRect` work calling it right after `startRunning` method of `AVCaptureSession`:

```
captureSession.startRunning()
let visibleRect = previewLayer.metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect(previewLayer.bounds)
captureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest = visibleRect
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks Avt.

Answer (score 15):

#### Swift 4:

```
captureSession?.startRunning()
let scanRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let rectOfInterest = layer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: scanRect)
metaDataOutput.rectOfInterest = rectOfInterest
```

Answer (score 10):

I managed to create an effect of having a region of interest. I tried all the proposed solutions but the region was either a CGPoint.zero or had inappropriate size (after converting frames to a 0-1 coordinate). It's actually a hack for those who can't get the `regionOfInterest` to work and doesn't optimize the detection.

In:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

I have the following code:

```
let visualCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
if self.viewfinderView.frame.contains(visualCodeObject.bounds) { 
    //visual code is inside the viewfinder, you can now handle detection
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this method

Comment: Thanks a lot. From all possible solutions i found this one most accurate and precise.

Comment: brilliant! the only one way make it works properly, as metadataOutputRectOfInterest seems like doesn't work (at least with my config) and calculating frame manually won't take into account gravity (content scaling)

Answer (score 2):

/// After

```
captureSession.startRunning()
```

/// Add this

```
if let videoPreviewLayer = self.videoPreviewLayer {
self.captureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest =
videoPreviewLayer.metadataOutputRectOfInterest(for:
self.getRectOfInterest())


fileprivate func getRectOfInterest() -> CGRect {
        let centerX = (self.frame.width / 2) - 100
        let centerY = (self.frame.height / 2) - 100
        let quadr: CGFloat = 200

        let myRect = CGRect(x: centerX, y: centerY, width: quadr, height: quadr)

        return myRect
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To read a QRCode/BarCode from a small rect(specific region) from a full camera view.

```
<br> **Mandatory to keep the below line after (start running)** <br>
[captureMetadataOutput setRectOfInterest:[_videoPreviewLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:scanRect] ];

[_captureSession startRunning];
[captureMetadataOutput setRectOfInterest:[_videoPreviewLayer metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect:scanRect] ];
```

Note:

1. `captureMetadataOutput` --> AVCaptureMetadataOutput
2. `_videoPreviewLayer`  --> AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
3. `scanRect`  --> Rect where you want the QRCode to be read.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are already solutions present and it's pretty late but i achieved mine by capturing the complete view image and then cropping it with specific rect.

```
 func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
    print(imageData)
    capturedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

    var crop = cropToPreviewLayer(originalImage: capturedImage!)

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let s = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KeyFobScanned") as! KeyFobScanned
    s.image = crop
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(s, animated: true)

}
}

private func cropToPreviewLayer(originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
guard let cgImage = originalImage.cgImage else { return nil }

let scanRect = CGRect(x: stackView.frame.origin.x, y: stackView.frame.origin.y, width: innerView.frame.size.width, height: innerView.frame.size.height)

let outputRect = videoPreviewLayer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: scanRect)

let width = CGFloat(cgImage.width)
let height = CGFloat(cgImage.height)

let cropRect = CGRect(x: outputRect.origin.x * width, y: outputRect.origin.y * height, width: outputRect.size.width * width, height: outputRect.size.height * height)

if let croppedCGImage = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect) {
    return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)
}

return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially unrelated, but the issue for me was screen orientation. On my portrait only app, I wanted to have a barcode scanner that just detects codes in a horizontal line in the middle of the screen. I thought this would work:

```
CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.4, width: 1, height: 0.2)
```

instead i had to switch x with y and width with height

```
CGRect(x: 0.4, y: 0, width: 0.2, height: 1)
```

Answer (score -3):

I wrote the following:

```
videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

And this worked for me, but I still don't know why.